# sql and getting elements around a specific one

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My sql database stores the highscores for the players of a game like this:

```
playerName
scores
```

To show the scores I'm trying to create a query that returns for a playerId "joe" the positon of joe as well as one player with more and less points than joe:

```
(rank) (playerName) (scores)
5000    luci       2001
5001    joe        1900
5002    marc       1750
```

(I added the rank here just to make it more clear. It isn't stored and represents just the position in the list when sorting by the scores)
Is there a way to do soemthing like this with a query without getting half of the database as result?

Comment: the `rank` column seems pretty convenient... can you just select where rank between joe's rank + or - 1 ?

Comment: @FOSC: The rank column dosn't exist at the moment as it would be redundant and I would have to update all rank rows if one user submits higher scores. But at the moment I'm pondering if it wouldn't be better to add such a row as the other path with multiple select/joins seems to be rather complex to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd ideally want to be using window functions to do this, namely `row_number()`, `lead()` and `lag()`.

These are not available in MySQL, but here are [a few workarounds](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/) (also [`row_number()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138914/mysql-query-problem/6138966#6138966), picked up from the same author).

---

Using window functions:

```
with
players as (
select row_number() over w as rank,
       playername,
       scores
from players
window w (order by scores desc)
),
player as (
select rank
from players
where playername = 'joe'
)
select rank,
       playername,
       scores
from players
join player on players.rank between player.rank - 1 and player.rank + 1
```

Alternatively (slightly faster):

```
with
player_range as (
select scores - 100 as scores -- or whatever is large enough based on your stats
from players
where playername = 'joe'
),
players as (
select row_number() over w as rank,
       players.playername,
       players.scores
from players
join player_range
on player_range.scores <= players.scores
window w (order by scores desc)
),
player as (
select rank
from players
where playername = 'joe'
)
select rank,
       playername,
       scores
from players
join player on players.rank between player.rank - 1 and player.rank + 1
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried to experiment with this a bit but they seem to be rather complex to me. Also they could eat up alot of performance, not sure about this. But thanks for the link.

Comment: If you need a rank/lead/lag from the DB, there's no escaping it. And yes, performance will suck short of using a [proper DB engine](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/index.html).

Comment: Ok, I will switch to Postgre this is probably the best solution. Just checked and my web host supports this.

Comment: I've updated the answer so you can see how it's done in postgres using with statements and window functions.

Answer (score 0):

To determine joe's rank you have to query the db and order by scores.

Comment: Yes, order by and limit is an option but with my knowledge i would get in this case 5002 entries or all of them and I wonder if there isn't a way with better performance / less data to receive from the database.