# How can I add a unique column to the union result?

Tags: mysql

Let say here is my query

```
  SELECT id as people_ID FROM user
    UNION 
  SELECT id as people_ID FROM client
```

What I want is give every row a unique ID that will increment by adding new column as below:

```
+------+-------------+
|  ID  |  people_ID  |
+------+-------------+
|  1   |    Alex     |
+------+-------------+
|  2   |   Kenny     |
+------+-------------+
|  3   |   David     |
+------+-------------+
|  4   |  Ashley     |
+------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to accomplish it?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `SELECT id AS people_ID FROM user`?

Comment: you could try `set id=0; select @id := @id + 1 from user ...  union select @id:=@id+1 from client` But there's no guarantee as to which order the subqueries would execute and return data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query: Using UNION and getting row number as part of SELECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122440/mysql-query-using-union-and-getting-row-number-as-part-of-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends which database you use but you could probably do it with rowid as a first column