# How to Calculate Top Customer in each City With Maximum order

Tags: mysql

I had create table name `customers` `orders` and `orderdetails` as follow

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) default NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) default NULL,
  `creditLimit` double default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`customerNumber`)
)

CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `requiredDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `shippedDate` datetime default NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`orderNumber`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` double NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`orderNumber`,`productCode`)
)
```

After that I have to find out top ordered customer from each city.I had calculated total order by each customer as given below but I don't know how to select top one customer from each city with maximum order.
So Question is how could I achive that.

```
SELECT o.customerNumber, ROUND( SUM( od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered ) , 2 ) AS totalOrder
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN orderDetails AS od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
GROUP BY o.customerNumber
ORDER BY totalOrder DESC
```

I'm using mysql.

Comment: I also heard about `partition`... could we solve this using `partition` or not.If we can solve then which method is efficient in reference to time for large data table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as [Sashi Kant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961125/sashi-kant) suggested but some edit is required on that answer

```
SELECT x.customerName, MAX( p.totalOrder ) , x.city
FROM (

SELECT o.customerNumber, ROUND( SUM( od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered ) , 2 ) AS totalOrder
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN orderDetails AS od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
GROUP BY o.customerNumber
ORDER BY totalOrder DESC
)p
INNER JOIN customers x ON p.customerNumber = x.customerNumber
GROUP BY city
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select tempTable.custNum, MAX(tempTable.totalOrder), customers.city
from
(
SELECT 
o.customerNumber as custNum, 
ROUND( SUM( od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered ) , 2 ) AS totalOrder,
city
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN orderDetails AS od ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
GROUP BY o.customerNumber
ORDER BY totalOrder DESC) as tempTable
 inner join customers on (tempTable.custNum = customers.customerNumber)
group by tempTable.city
```

Comment: phpmyadmin says [Every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363918/mysql-error-1248-42000-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

Comment: there is no `city` field on `orders` and `orderDetails` table

Comment: I thought you can do the join with the customer's table, Please dont expect an end to end solution from our side,
By the way, have updated the query, check now

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(z.total),z.customerNumber,z.city,z.customerName from (select c.customerNumber,c.city,c.customerName, 
   sum(od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered) as total 
   from customers c, orders o, orderdetails od 
   where c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber 
      and o.orderNumber = od.orderdetails 
   group by c.customerNumber) as z  group by z.customerNumber,z.city
```