# select column from multiple unknown tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a lot of dynamically created nearly similar looking tables according to the scheme "prefix + number", eg "t1", "t2", "t343" etc. All those tables have a cross-table unique row named `identifier` that I like to select within one query:

```
SELECT
  `identifier`
FROM
(
  SELECT
    `TABLE_NAME`
  FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE
    `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 't%'
);
```

But this returns: **ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias**

EDIT: according to the comments I modified my query like this:

```
SELECT
  A.identifier
FROM
(
  SELECT
    `TABLE_NAME` AS identifier
  FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
  WHERE
    `TABLE_NAME` LIKE 't%'
) A;
```

But this selects only the table names from the subquery but not the column `identifier` from these tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363918/mysql-error-1248-42000-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)  OR [What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)

Comment: No, not really. I'm not a mySQL expert. If I modify the query like `SELECT A.identifier FROM ( ... ) AS A`, I get **(42S22): Unknown column 'A.identifier' in 'field list'** and when I select `A.*` I get all the table names from the subquery as result.

Comment: When you need a column name `identifier`, you should create an alias like:  `SELECT x.identifier FROM ( SELECT TABLE_NAME as identifier FROM ... ) x;`

Comment: Or, you could do: `SELECT TABLE_NAME as identifier FROM ( SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ... ) x;`   Where `x` is the alias given to the result-table of the sub-query.

Comment: Doesn't work:
`SELECT A.identifier FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME as identifier FROM ...) A;` still outputs the table names from the subquery but does not select the "identifier" column from these tables.

Comment: It is (very) unclear what you want to be returned from the query. What do you mean by the "identifier" column ?

Comment: I have dynamically created tabels like "t1", "t2", t3" etc but I don't now how much of them only the scheme: prefix "t" + number. Now I want to run a query on all of them like `select row1 form t1`, `select row1 form t2`, `select row1 form t3` etc. But I want do do this in one query so I thought I could get the table names from **information_schema.TABLES**. But I begin to understand that this seems to be the wrong approach because the result of the subquery is a table that contains all the table names as strings. Is there another way to reach my original goal?

Comment: I edited the original question to make it hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table dynamically, and you want to query all of them, you can create an SQL statement dynamically like:

```sql
select
   group_concat(
   concat(
       'SELECT ',
       '''',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,''',',
       TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,'.', COLUMN_NAME,
       ' FROM ',
       TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME)
      separator ' union all ')
from information_schema.`COLUMNS` c  
where table_schema='test'             -- the schema name where your tables are
  and table_name  regexp '^t[0-9]+$'  -- table name starts with t and ends with number
  and COLUMN_NAME = 'i'               -- i choose `i` as the column to be selected
;
```

This will produce a SQL statement like:

```sql
select
    'test.t1',
    test.t1.i
from
    test.t1
union all
select
    'test.t2',
    test.t2.i
from
    test.t2
union all
select
    'test.t3',
    test.t3.i
from
    test.t3
```

When putting all of this in a stored procedure, you can use [PREPARE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) and [EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) to execute this created statement.

Above is just an example of an SQL statement, you should change it to your needs.